# Page margins in PHPExcel 1.7.8 mPDF

Tags: pdf, phpexcel, margins, mpdf

I'm attempting to set page margins in PHPExcel 1.7.8 using mPDF as the renderer, and I'm getting nowhere.  I found a thread somewhere where Mark Baker mentions having written in support for page margins for pdfs for version 1.7.8, but I've come up empty as far as how to actually implement them.

Near as I can tell, it's something separate from setting margins for Excel documents, as the following works fine if I set my output to xls:

```
$pageMargins = $sheet->getPageMargins();
$pageMargins->setTop('.25');
$pageMargins->setBottom('.25');
$pageMargins->setLeft('.2');
$pageMargins->setRight('.2');
```

When I switch back to pdf output, the margins appear to be nearly an inch on each side.  I've become incredibly frustrated, as the few references to pdf margins in PHPExcel refer to older versions, which only had tcPDF, and I couldn't get to work at all back when I was using 1.7.6.

I thought I was close once I got pdf rendering working in the first place, and I'm so close to done.  I've just spent 8ish hours overhauling the code to output an html page that can be sent to mPDF directly, but PHPExcel is so much easier to work with for pages needing a very specific format as mine does, that I'd rather do it in PHPExcel if possible.

Has anyone worked with margins in PHPExcel using mPDF?

Comment: If you'd posted it on the PHPExcel issues log on codeplex, or on the github issues list, I might have added it to the TODO list

Comment: Fair enough.  Done and done, on the CodePlex issue tracker.  (And please don't think I'm just hear to bitch about what I can't get PHPExcel to do - people at work think I'm some sort of wizard for being able to output reports directly to Excel from a browser page.  For that, I am eternally grateful.)

Comment: I have started to look at it, though each PDF rendering library has its own methods so I have to code for each individually... but as a logged issue, it means I can actually track the work. As I'm currently finalising the 1.7.9 release, hopefully I'll manage to get them all working for then

Answer (score 0):

Somebody posted a workaround on Codeplex back in November 2012, and I just added a fix for the units (PHPExcel's margin being in inches, mPDF being in millimeters).
Find it here: https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/398021